# jQuery Ajax Get Variable From PHP and Set Value To Textbox

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

How to get PHP variable set to Ajax ?

Example I have PHP code like this (update_prod_rev.php) :

```
<?php
$start_date1 = $_POST['start_date1'];
$end_date1 = $_POST['end_date1'];
?>
```

and My jQuery Ajax :

```
$.ajax(
{
    'data' : $('form').serialize(),
    'type' : 'POST',
    'url' : 'update_prod_rev.php',
    'success' : function(data)
    {
        alert.html(data).fadeIn().delay(2000).fadeOut('slow');  
$("#a").val(data.value);
}
});
```

Now I want to set that variable to textbox.

```
<input type="text" name="a" id="a"/>
<input type="text" name="b" id="b"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your php code doesn't seem to echo/return JSON formated data.

Here's an example with PHP and JQuery. I'm using getJSON, but you could the same thing with ajax method and some parameters.

Now, heres some jquery we used to get JSON data from the server.

```
var title = '.....'
$.getJSON('getActivite.php?title=' + title, null,
        function(data){
            $("#currentId").val(data.ID);
            $("#nomActivite").val(data.Nom);
            $("#Description").val(data.Description);
            $("#DateEvent").val(data.Date);
});
```

As you can see, you receive the data variable from the server callback function. This variable contains the JSON data.

On the PHP side, we have

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    mysql_connect("localhost","root") or die (" NOPE . [" . mysql_error() . "]");
    mysql_select_db("garderie");


    $title  = $_GET["title"]; // we received this from the json call


    $query = "  select a.ActiviteID as ActiviteID  , rtrim(a.Nom) as Nom, a.Description from activites a inner join .....' ";


    $result = mysql_query($query);       
    $ligne  = mysql_fetch_array($result);

    $data = array(
        'ID'            => $ligne["ActiviteID"],
        'Nom'           => $ligne["Nom"],
        'Description'   => $ligne["Description"],
        'Date'          => $date
    );

    mysql_close();

    echo (json_encode($data));
?>
```